# Why is my Xcode 5.1.1 simulator not working?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to create an app.

I have **Xcode 5.1.1** but have been having this issue ever since I downloaded **Xcode** (2 versions ago)

Even though I have code written and it compiles successfully, when I go to use the **simulator** (any simulator).

It opens up just plain black and stays plain black, it doesn't change.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't an Xcode problem. It's probably a problem with your app.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the Simulator?

Comment: Does your code run on a device?

Comment: Does the *simulator* open up black, or your *app* opens up black? Can you use the menu options in the similar to do something like go to the home screen? (I think that's Shift+Command+H.)

Comment: two things i've noticed, the xcode 5.1.1 doesnt support ios 6 projects in it's default simulator. the other is deleting the app from the simulator can fix problems

Comment: the steps i've used i think are hit stop, the simulator reverts to a home screen. if your app was ever installed it there. delete it like you delete an ap on a phone

Comment: click iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

Answer (score 0):

Its not problem with Xcode. Its problem with the simulator version you are running the app on.

1. Place some NSLog statements in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc. methods, and see what is going wrong.
2. Download old simulators and try running on them.
3. Better you clean builds and remove the app from the simulator everytime you run until you

see good results.

Answer (score 0):

This could be for multiple reasons so I'll give multiple bits of advice.

1. Which simulator are you trying to run? Retina 3.5inch, Retina 4inch or Retina 4inch 64bit, if you're trying to run the 64bit, all I'll say is don't
2. Have you tried cleaning your app? Shift + Command + K
3. Have you made sure that your deployment target is correct? Project > Targets > Deployment info and that's how you change it, I run 7.1 but that's up to you and your project.
4. In the iOS simulator, on the task bar at the top click Hardware then home or Shift + Command + H. If it goes to the home screen it's the app.
5. In the iOS simulator again go to the top task bar and click iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

If none of these work, I'll try and help you further.